# Mqtt causes memory leak issue with NodeJS version upgrade more than 0.12.9

Tags: node.js, sockets, memory-leaks, mqtt

Here is what I am facing.When node version **"0.12.9"** is used with MQTT version **"1.4.1"** I did not run into any issues.
When used node version **"6.10.0"** with MQTT version **"1.4.1"** ,Node js throws the below error.After this happens all of a sudden no request is accepted by the server.This happens slowly in one hour after the Node version upgrade to **"6.10.0"**

> (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 offline
>   listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
>   Trace
>       at MqttClient.addListener (events.js:179:15)
>       at MqttClient.once (events.js:204:8)

Any thoughts on this would be great.

Comment: Does it show this error again later with a higher value than 11? If it's only showing the message once then it's not a problem, it's just a warning that you have more than 10 listeners.

Comment: This is the only error logs which I got as a reference for the node version upgrade. But the actual cause seems to be something else, which is making the server unresponsive and all calls starts failing for which I am unable to identify the root cause.